# Liberty encoded datasource password not working

Tags: passwords, websphere, encode

I'm trying to secure a Liberty 20.0.0.3 docker image and can't get an encoded password for a datasource to work. The plain text password is working fine.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
securityUtility encode --encoding=aes mypa$$word
{aes}ADPrOj1GfH/9Am3TSqT7MLN0+sRPkXHUAy7RIk+dbRmZR0fEQTEkzHv1lDTnGhGeaA==
```

In my datasource configuration I have:

```
<dataSource id="DS1" jndiName="jdbc/DS1" transactional="true">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="MSSQL"/>
    <properties.microsoft.sqlserver serverName="myserver" instanceName="myinstance" databaseName="mydatabase" user="myuser" password="{aes}ADPrOj1GfH/9Am3TSqT7MLN0+sRPkXHUAy7RIk+dbRmZR0fEQTEkzHv1lDTnGhGeaA==" />
</dataSource>
```

which gives:

```
### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Login failed for user 'myuser'. ClientConnectionId:d521779d-9316-4adf-ab61-9118cf66a940 DSRA0010E: SQL State = S0001, Error Code = 18,456
```

I then changed the configuration to this:

```
<dataSource id="DS1" jndiName="jdbc/DS1" transactional="true">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="MSSQL"/>
    <containerAuthData user="myuser" password="{aes}ADPrOj1GfH/9Am3TSqT7MLN0+sRPkXHUAy7RIk+dbRmZR0fEQTEkzHv1lDTnGhGeaA==" />
    <properties.microsoft.sqlserver serverName="myserver" instanceName="myinstance" databaseName="mydatabase" />
</dataSource>
```

and I get

```
### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Login failed for user ''. ClientConnectionId:34a029da-e38a-4d54-a943-9c975009ccba DSRA0010E: SQL State = S0001, Error Code = 18,456
```

Finally, I tried moving password to bootstrap.properties and using as a property

```
bootstrap.properties
pwd={aes}ADPrOj1GfH/9Am3TSqT7MLN0+sRPkXHUAy7RIk+dbRmZR0fEQTEkzHv1lDTnGhGeaA==

<dataSource id="DS1" jndiName="jdbc/DS1" transactional="true">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="MSSQL"/>
    <properties.microsoft.sqlserver serverName="myserver" instanceName="myinstance" databaseName="mydatabase" user="myuser" password="${pwd}" />
</dataSource>

### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Login failed for user 'myuser'. ClientConnectionId:d521779d-9316-4adf-ab61-9118cf66a940 DSRA0010E: SQL State = S0001, Error Code = 18,456
```

I'm running the securityUtility command on the docker container so there shouldn't be any OS diffs that would cause an issue. My actual password does contain a $ character though so could that be throwing it off? I also read the code page compatibility should be checked, how do I do that on a docker image terminal?

Comment: Do more basic forms of encoding like XOR work? Also, when using AES encryption you need to set the AES encryption key in your server.xml like this: `<variable name="wlp.password.encryption.key" value="yourKey" />` see this page for more details: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/cwlp_pwd_encrypt.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply Andy.  Unfortunately not, tried xor too and no joy there either. I had also tried using a key rather tan relying on a default generated by the container and saving to server.xml and bootstrap.properties but again with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this knowledge center doc](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_command_securityutil.html) for the securityUtility command, some operating systems require single quotes around the supplied arguments.  I noticed that if I try the following on Mac,

```
./securityUtility encode --encoding=aes mypa$$word
```

vs

```
./securityUtility encode --encoding=aes 'mypa$$word'
```

they generate different output.
And furthermore, when I decode them,
the former decodes to:

```
mypa15652word
```

whereas the latter decodes to

```
mypa$$word
```

If you are wondering where the 15652 comes from, if I run

```
echo $$
```

from the Mac command prompt, I get back 15652, which looks to be the current proccess id.

Try adding the single quotes when encoding the password and see if that helps.

Comment: Cheers njr! Because my password had a $ character the generated encoded String was incorrect. By adding the single quotes the password was able to be decoded correctly.